# Intellij IDEA Spring Boot Shuts Down Immediately on Startup

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm working on a personal project with spring boot and have encountered the problem of application shutting down immediately on startup when I try running it via IntelliJ IDEA. It seems to startup fine when I try running the project via command-line.

**Console on Startup from IntelliJ**

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.3)
    
    2022-01-23 09:11:42.313  INFO 23267 --- [           main] c.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication   : Starting UrlShortenerApplication using Java 16.0.2 on Pratyushs-Air with PID 23267 (/Users/solixious/projects/url-shortener/target/classes started by solixious in /Users/solixious/projects/url-shortener)
    2022-01-23 09:11:42.318 DEBUG 23267 --- [           main] c.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication   : Running with Spring Boot v2.6.3, Spring v5.3.15
    2022-01-23 09:11:42.319  INFO 23267 --- [           main] c.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2022-01-23 09:11:43.281  INFO 23267 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2022-01-23 09:11:43.372  INFO 23267 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 78 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
    2022-01-23 09:11:44.151  INFO 23267 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
    2022-01-23 09:11:44.195  INFO 23267 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
    2022-01-23 09:11:44.350  INFO 23267 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
    2022-01-23 09:11:44.434  INFO 23267 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2022-01-23 09:11:44.887  INFO 23267 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    2022-01-23 09:11:44.902  INFO 23267 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    2022-01-23 09:11:45.509  INFO 23267 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
    2022-01-23 09:11:45.515  INFO 23267 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2022-01-23 09:11:46.118  INFO 23267 --- [           main] c.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication   : Started UrlShortenerApplication in 4.449 seconds (JVM running for 5.076)
    2022-01-23 09:11:46.125  INFO 23267 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2022-01-23 09:11:46.128  INFO 23267 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2022-01-23 09:11:46.137  INFO 23267 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Console log when executed from terminal**

```
url-shortener % mvn spring-boot:run  
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com:url-shortener >--------------------------
[INFO] Building url-shortener 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.3:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ url-shortener >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ url-shortener ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ url-shortener ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ url-shortener ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/solixious/projects/url-shortener/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ url-shortener ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.3:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ url-shortener <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.3:run (default-cli) @ url-shortener ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.3)

2022-01-23 09:13:14.930  INFO 23680 --- [           main] c.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication   : Starting UrlShortenerApplication using Java 16.0.2 on Pratyushs-Air with PID 23680 (/Users/solixious/projects/url-shortener/target/classes started by solixious in /Users/solixious/projects/url-shortener)
2022-01-23 09:13:14.932 DEBUG 23680 --- [           main] c.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication   : Running with Spring Boot v2.6.3, Spring v5.3.15
2022-01-23 09:13:14.932  INFO 23680 --- [           main] c.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-01-23 09:13:15.567  INFO 23680 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-01-23 09:13:15.626  INFO 23680 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 50 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-01-23 09:13:16.144  INFO 23680 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-01-23 09:13:16.152  INFO 23680 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-01-23 09:13:16.153  INFO 23680 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-01-23 09:13:16.418  INFO 23680 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2022-01-23 09:13:16.432  INFO 23680 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-01-23 09:13:16.432  INFO 23680 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1447 ms
2022-01-23 09:13:16.585  INFO 23680 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-01-23 09:13:16.616  INFO 23680 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
2022-01-23 09:13:16.718  INFO 23680 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-01-23 09:13:16.772  INFO 23680 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-01-23 09:13:17.097  INFO 23680 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-01-23 09:13:17.110  INFO 23680 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2022-01-23 09:13:17.462  INFO 23680 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-01-23 09:13:17.467  INFO 23680 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-01-23 09:13:17.733  WARN 23680 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-01-23 09:13:17.974  INFO 23680 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-01-23 09:13:17.986  INFO 23680 --- [           main] c.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication   : Started UrlShortenerApplication in 3.514 seconds (JVM running for 3.891)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>url-shortener</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>url-shortener</name>
    <description>A Basic URL Shortener</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
# MySQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/url_shortener
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# Jackson
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL

# Logging
logging.level.com.urlshortener=DEBUG

# JSP
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**Github Link to Project:** https://github.com/Solixious/url-shortener

I have tried invalidating IntelliJ cache and clearing the m2 repository. But it did not resolve the issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try after removing this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. But I got the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of bug in IntelliJ IDEA. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224547